# how to maintain #3 google rank in site redesign?

Tags: seo

I have a simple three page website that ranks #3 in organic Google rank. The current site is looking outdated and in early stages of a redesign project. Is there any way to change the markup of the entire site and keep the rank or make it better?

[website: http://www.polytechnicsolutions.com/](http://www.polytechnicsolutions.com/)

Comment: How do we assess your website without a link? ;)

Comment: added a link to the site: http://www.polytechnicsolutions.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Markup**

Don't use table-based layouts. Use appropriate markup such as headings, microtags, images (with alt text!), and so on. You're missing meta description tags. You don't have a doctype, and the [cut doesn't validate](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://www.polytechnicsolutions.com/&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0).

Lots of improvement here alone.

**Content**

You have no content to speak of. If you want to become an authoritative resource, you need to be pushing community content hard. Videos, tutorials, case studies, contests, and so forth. SEOmoz has many great guides for thinking up content for tough niches. Trust me it's possible: I've seen a radiology company in particular produce killer content, that in turn produced a massive community. Yes, for *radiology*, a contender for the most difficult niche to write for long-term.

Don't be discouraged by not having a 'fun' niche. Although, yours certainly isn't bad.

**Link Building**

You have no links to speak of. If you *really* want to rank in Google (and please, shoot higher than #3) you need backlinks. Again, looks like the [SEOmoz beginner guide](http://www.seomoz.org/beginners-guide-to-seo) would help you out here.

Most white-hat methods these days include asking politely for links or guest blogging. You can go a little further than that and participate in grey-hat methods without any harm, but do be careful. And be sure to start multiple sites to test methods on before trying them on your flagship domain.

Best of luck.

Comment: while searching for technical screening service, the site comes up third and its been unchanged for about 7 years. so even as it is its ranking high in its specific search words. Thanks for the great info, the new site is all based on DIV tags and will have meta data.

Comment: 'technical screening service' doesn't show up in Adwords Keyword Tool - meaning it's not worth targeting in your SEO campaign. Try to think of what others would search for to find you. Personally, it would not be technical screening service for me.

Comment: What would you suggest I target as keywords? We always believed there to be little competition in the type of service we provide hence our high rank (also our targeted copy). Please advise...

Comment: I'm not familiar with that niche. Your best bet is to have some fun with AKT: https://adwords.google.com/o/KeywordTool

Comment: will changing markup of a site hurt page rank?

Comment: Pagerank isn't determined by your markup, but rather links. It WILL hurt your rankings temporarily though. Google has to recrawl your website, and in your case, you should see a good benefit if you follow my advice. Takes 1-2 weeks to get back to where you were, max.